# List view not showing any records for Customer Community user

Tags: customer-portal, customer-community, list-view

When I log in as a Customer Community user, when I go to the Orders tab, in the Recent section it is showing Orders of which I am the owner. But when I am going to the list view to display all orders, not a single record is showing. As the records are showing in the Recent section, this is not an access/sharing issue. Then why does the list view not show any records even though no filters are added?
Also, when I create a new Order from the New button on the related list in the Customer page, it is not appearing in the related list.

Comment: Did you check if there is any code or workflow to change the owner immediately after creation? Only then it is possible that right after the creation of a record, it is not visible to you.

Comment: No, the owner is not changed. He can see the order in the recent items section, but not in list views without filters.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with OWD setting on Order object. See if the current OWD setting is 'Private'. If you change the setting to 'Controlled by Parent' then the community user would be able to see all the orders related to his/her customer record.

Comment: But then why is it coming in Recent Items section? It should not appear there also if it is a sharing related issue.